# Passing the parameter

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, var

I am passing the parameter to the function as a `var` type. It is not accepting, how do I pass to the function?

Example

```
var Input = ................

listview1.itemsource = getinput(Input);

public List<answers>getinput(var inp)
{
................
..................
}
```

Here the function is not accepting the `var`. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**var** can only be used when a local variable is declared and initialized in the same statement; the variable cannot be initialized to null, or to a method group or an anonymous function.

MSDN : [Implicitly Typed Local Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`var` is used for type inference, not to declare a dynamic variable. Use the actual input type as the type for `inp`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not accepting the third line because your function is of the type `void` and you try to assign the result of that function to `listview1.itemsource`.

Comment: sorry it will return a List<answers>

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you're mixing implicitly typed variables (type inference), and an explictly typed function signature.

What you should have is:

```
var Input = txtQuestion.text; // Implicitly typed variable of type string
listview1.itemsource = getinput(Input); 

// Strongly typed method taking string, returning List<answers> 
public List<answers>getinput(string question) 
{ 
    var result = new List<answers>();
    result.Add(answer);
    return result; 
}
```

Sorry if this doesn't exactly match your code, but it should demonstrate what you're after.

The var keyword is used to infer the type of a variable from the right-hand side of the assignment operator. In a method's signature, there's no assignment operator, so inference can't take place. Further, you could always pass any number of types derived from a base class, which would make it difficult for the compiler to determine the correct type of the argument. (Did you mean DbReader, SqlDbReader, or IDbReader?)

Variables can be inferred. Parameters cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `object` in the function instead of `var`. Then cast it to the appropriate type within the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void getinput(object inp)
{
................
..................
}
```

As soon as C# is strongly-typed language, the compiler always knows, what real type your variable belongs to:

```
var Input = ....
```

Type of .... is always known. That's why you can't declare

```
var a;
```

and this is EXACLTLY what you are trying to do in

```
public void getinput(var inp)
{
    ................
    ..................
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` is just used in the JavaScript code as a variant. If you are using `var` then you can use string or use object.

```
public void getinput(object inp) 
{ 
    ................ 
    .................. 
} 


public void getinput(string inp) 
{ 
    ................ 
    .................. 
}
```